# Got error when importing function react componets

Tags: reactjs

I have a function componet in react which get some props as follow:

```
export default function ThermoBreastCancerIntroPage(props) {
  console.log('rest is logged in is')
  console.log(props.is_logged_in);
  const [is_logged_in, set_is_logged_in] = useState(props.is_looged_in);
  const [fname, set_fname] = useState(props.fname);
  const [lname, set_lname] = useState(props.lname);
```

in my index.js I import it and then want to use it

```
import ThermoBreastCancerPage from "views/LandingPage/ThermoBreastCancerPage.js";

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router history={hist}>
        <Switch>
           
          <Route path="/thermo-breast-cancer" component={<ThermoBreastCancerPage is_logged_in='false' fname='' lname='' />} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

But in above, I got error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

when I change to component={ThermoBreastCancerPage} I wont get any error but I have to pass props in some way. I am new to react and not sure where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should use values directly from state, not pass props to the component.

Comment: I want to pass inital state values so I used props.

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing this

```js
<Route path="/thermo-breast-cancer" component={<ThermoBreastCancerPage is_logged_in='false' fname='' lname='' />} />
```

to this

```js
<Route path="/thermo-breast-cancer">
  <ThermoBreastCancerPage is_logged_in='false' fname='' lname='' />
</Route>
```

Comment: There are a few ways to render components inside a `<Route />`, and all three of them receive the same props (although their behavior is slightly different). You can read more about them here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, to pass props on component in `Route` `component` you have to use an arrow function in this way:

```
<Route path="/thermo-breast-cancer" component={() => <ThermoBreastCancerPage is_logged_in='false' fname='' lname='' />} />
```

Comment: I think you'd want to use `render={..}` instead of `component={...}` here, if you want the route props to be passed to the component

Comment: @Shadab Yes you could use render like `render={(props) => ...}` but also component with arrow function works.